# parse heroku cloudcode function not linked/working

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

I am going in circles for a day now. I cant get the hello cloud function to work.
I followed this tutorial: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-heroku-parse/

```
1) I linked heroku to my parse account
2) I created an app from scratch with CLI (like in the video)
3) I use 'parse deploy' and i see its pushed to heroku
4) On my Parse Dashboard - Webhooks page i see its linked with the app
5) Not knowing if this is important but if go to Cloud Code in the parse dashboard it says i havent deployed anything.
```

When i use the command "parse functions" to see the webhooks of the cloudcode I see 2 empty lines as a response. Instead of the hello function.

When I try to use the Api Console in the dashboard to check if "functions/hello" works i get this response:

```
RESPONSE
{
"code": 141,
"error": "function not found"
}
```

What am I missing or are the docs outdated ? I think it has to do with this register-webhook.js like its not getting called or something. Its only in package.json as a start and record parameter. But i dont have enough knowledge of heroku to see if it is even called.

Comment: Do you use parse-server or parse.com? ... Parse server is free and you can run it with single Heroku button, just check parse-server on github

Comment: @Mazel Tov not using it but plan to use it as soon I have fixed this cloud code. What I want to achieve is to check for duplicates with the before save hook. But I can't get it to work

Comment: stop using parse.com because it is not 100% the same as the open sourced server, you will have to modify cloud code for sure cause you cant use Parse.currentUser() or MasterKey the same way as on parse.com